# Why does sudo prevent catching SIGTSTP (Ctrl+Z)?

Tags: sudo, c, signal

This program is written to catch [SIGTSTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#Sending_signals) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) and bypass its normal effect, printing a message and returning to its normal operation instead of allowing its process to be suspended:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
void sigproc(void);
int main(void)
{
        signal(SIGTSTP , sigproc);
        while(1);
        return 0;
}

void sigproc()
{
        printf("CTRL + z");
}
```

It works fine without sudo. But when launched with sudo, the program doesn't run as expected.

Comment: This is generic enough to belong on [so]. If not [so], then [unix.se].

Comment: This is about sudo, which is not even on all Unix-like systems. Even if this were fundamentally a programming question, it would be on-topic. And I'm not sure it is even mostly about programming--presumably sudo's effect on SIGTSTP handling applies in general, and not just for this particular code.